# Proper implementation of "Third order" Kneser-Key smoothing (for Trigram model)

Tags: python, nlp, smoothing

In the following code, I'm trying to compute the probability of a tri-gram according to Knesr-Kney smoothing method based on fixed discount. I go through the important papers describing Knesr-Kney from  [Goodman &Chen](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGovvxzPzLAhWGRhQKHdqPBA8QFgg7MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Faclweb.org%2Fanthology%2FP%2FP96%2FP96-1041.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE7l6YZdCKZtCKoaWPqFUBzqF_lcw&sig2=pMyTAxWHFbLni9bRNi2UCQ&bvm=bv.118817766,d.ZWU) and [Dan Jurafsky](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf). This [question] (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114863/in-kneser-ney-smoothing-how-are-unseen-words-handled) on stack exchange is a good summary for the bi-gram case.

I find it hard to drive an implementation of Kneser-Ney from the mathematical formals for the tri-gram case because they are fairly complex and difficult to digest.
After a long search i could not find an explanation to the method by code.

I assume a **closed vocabulary** and  want to check whether this code is a correct implementation ?

Specifically, the function `score_trigram(self,tri_g)` takes a tri-gram as tuple ('u','v','w') and tries to compute the log of its probability, according to Knesey-Kney. The dicts shown in the init method store the frequencies of unigrams, bigrams, trigrams learned based on some corpus.

**Just assume the those frequecy counts are properly initialized and given.**

if we have a trigram (a,b,c), then high level formula of Kneser-kney for a trigram case with non-zero count:

P((a,b,c)) = P_ML_discounted((a,b,c)) + total_discount_1 * P_KN((b,c))

P_ML_discounted((a,b,c)) = count((a,b,c)) - discount/count((a,b))

total_discount_1 = discount * follow_up_count((a,b)) / count( (a,b))

P_KN((b,c)) = continuation_count of((b,c)) / count_of_unique_trigrams +
                total_discount_2 *P_KN(c)

total_discount_2 = discount+follow_up_count(b) /count_unique_bigrams

P_KN(c) = continuation_count(c) - discount/count_unique_bigrams +  discount*1/vocabulary_size

I have two questions:
1- are the previous equations correct for Knesery-Kney trigram case ?

2-are the corresponding scoring functions in the code correct implementation?

class CustomLanguageModel:

```
def __init__(self, corpus):
    """Initialize your data structures in the constructor."""
    ### n-gram counts
    # trigram dict entry > ('word_a','word_b','word_c') : 10
    self.trigramCounts = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    # bigram dict entry > ('word_a','word_b') : 11
    self.bigramCounts = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    # unigram dict entry > 'word_a' : 15
    self.unigramCounts = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    ###Kneser-kney(KN) counts

    '''The follow_up count of a bi-gram (a,b) is the number of unique tri-grams 
    starts with (a,b), for example if the frequency of (a,b,c) tri-gram is 3,
    this increments the follow_up count of (a,b) by one,also if the frequency
    of (a,b,d) is 5 this adds one to the continuation count of (y,z).'''
    # dict entry as >  ('word_a','word_b') : 7
    self.bigram_follow_up_dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    '''The continuation count of a bigram (y,z) is the number of unique trigrams
    ends with (y,z), for example if the frequency of (x,y,z) trigram is 3,
    this increments the continuation count of (y,z) by one,
    also if the frequency of (r,y,z) is 5 this adds one to the continuation count of (y,z).'''
    # dict entry as > ('word_a','word_b') : 5
    self.bigram_continuation_dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    '''The continuation count of a unigam 'z' is the number of unique bigrams ends
    with 'z',for example if the frequency of ('y','z') bigram is 3, this increments 
    the continuation count of 'z' by one. Also if the frequency of ('w','z') is 5,
    this adds one to the continuation count of 'z'.
    '''
    # dict entry as >  'word_z' : 5
    self.unigram_continuation_count = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    '''The follow-up count of a unigam 'a' is the number of unique bigrams starts
    with 'a',for example if the frequency of ('a','b') bigram is 3, this increments
    the continuation count of 'a' by one. Also if the frequency of ('a','c') is 5,
    this adds one to the continuationcount of 'a'. '''
    # dict entry as >  'word_a' : 5
    self.unigram_follow_up_count = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    # total number of words, fixed discount
    self.total =0 , self.d=0.75 ,self.train(corpus)

def train(self, corpus):
    # count and initialize the dictionaries
    pass
def score_trigram(self,tri_g): 

    score = 0.0 , w1 = tri_g[0], w2 = tri_g[1] , w3 = tri_g[2]
    # use the trigram if it has a frequency > 0
    if self.trigramCounts[(w1,w2,w3)] > 0 and self.bigramCounts[(w1,w2)] > 0 :
        score += self.top_level_trigram_prob(*tri_g)
    # otherwise use the bigram (w2,w3) as an approximation
    else :
        if self.bigramCounts[(w2,w3)] > 0  and self.unigramCounts[w2]> 0:
            score = score + self.top_level_bigram_prob(w2,w3)
        ## otherwise use the unigram w3 as an approximation
        else:
            score += math.log(self.pkn_unigram(w3))               
    return score

def top_level_trigram_prob(self,w1,w2,w3):
    score=0.0
    term1 = max(self.trigramCounts[(w1,w2,w3)]-self.d,0)/self.bigramCounts[(w1,w2)]
    alfa = self.d * self.bigram_follow_set[(w1,w2)] / len(self.bigram_follow_set)
    term2 = self.pkn_bigram(w2,w3)
    score += math.log(term1+ alfa* term2)
    return score  

def top_level_bigram_prob(self,w1,w2):
    score=0.0
    term1 = max(self.bigramCounts[(w1,w2)]-self.d,0)/self.unigramCounts[w1]
    alfa = self.d * self.unigram_follow_set[w1]/self.unigramCounts[w1]
    term2 = self.pkn_unigram (w2)
    score += math.log(term1+ alfa* term2)
    return score 

def pkn_bigram(self,w1,w2):           
    return self.pkn_bigram_contuation(w1,w2) + self.pkn_bigram_follow_up(w1) * self.pkn_unigram(w2)


def pkn_bigram_contuation (self,w1,w2):
    ckn= self.bigram_continuation_dict[(w1,w2)]
    term1 = (max(ckn -self.d,0)/len(self.bigram_continuation_dict))        
    return term1

def pkn_bigram_follow_up (self,w1):
    ckn = self.unigram_follow_dict[w1]
    alfa = self.d * ckn / len(self.bigramCounts)
    return alfa  

def pkn_unigram (self,w1):
    #continuation of w1 + lambda uniform
    ckn= self.unigram_continuation_dict[w1]
    p_cont= float(max(ckn - self.d,0)) / len(self.bigramCounts)+ 1.0/len(self.unigramCounts )
    return p_cont
```

Comment: Before diving into the implementation, please show us exactly the equations you are implementing.

Comment: This is my very first question on stackoverflow, are the equations included clear ?

Comment: can you use the math environment for readability of the equations?

Comment: my knowledge is that math environment is not enabled on stackoverflow,  it is only working on math exchange or the like, is not that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your first question.

Below I labeled are your equations (and I corrected your typo in (5) and added max(,0) in (2) and (6), according to your code)

(1) P((a,b,c)) = P_ML_discounted((a,b,c)) + total_discount_1 * P_KN((b,c))

(2) P_ML_discounted((a,b,c)) = max(count((a,b,c)) - discount, 0)/count((a,b))

(3) total_discount_1 = discount * follow_up_count((a,b)) / count( (a,b))

(4) P_KN((b,c)) = continuation_count of((b,c)) / count_of_unique_trigrams + total_discount_2 *P_KN(c)

(5) total_discount_2 = discount * follow_up_count(b) /count_unique_bigrams

(6) P_KN(c) = max(continuation_count(c) - discount, 0)/count_unique_bigrams + discount*1/vocabulary_size

Regarding the correctness of above equations:

(1)~(3): correct

(4) (5): not correct. In both equations, count_of_unique_trigrams should be replaced by "count of unique trigrams whose second word is b", i.e. the unique count of trigrams in the form (*,b,*).

And I see in your code, pkn_bigram_contuation() does discount continuation_count of((b,c)), which is right. It's not reflected in your equation (4) , though.

(6) I think you were using implementing equation (4.37) from [Dan Jurafsky](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf). The problem is that the authors are not clear on how to calculate \lambda(\epsilon) to make the unigram probabilities normalize correctly.

Actually the unigram probability does not need to be discounted (see the slide titled "Kneser‐Ney Details" on page 5 [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~klein/cs288/fa14/slides/fa14lecture2-6pp.pdf)), so (6) could simply be

P_KN(c) = continuation_count(c)/count_unique_bigrams.

Comment: On what basis do you say - "count_of_unique_trigrams should be replaced by "count of unique trigrams whose second word is b" ?